# Testing with 2 different mocks in Jasmine

Tags: typescript, testing, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a ts guard like so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AppEssentialsGuard implements CanActivate {

  private readonly DEFAULT_APP_ID = 'def';

  constructor(private appsService: AppsService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const url = this.getDefaultAppUrl();
    if (url) {
      window.open(url);
    }
    return false;
  }

  private getDefaultAppUrl(): string {
    const myApp = this.appsService.getAllApps()
      .find(app => app.appId === this.DEFAULT_APP_ID);
    return myApp ? myApp.url : null;
  }
}
```

I am writing tests for it as follows:

```
describe('AppEssentialsGuard', () => {
  let guard: AppEssentialsGuard;
  let appsService: AppsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        mockProvider(RequesterService),
        {provide: AppsService, useClass: AppsServiceMock}
      ]
    });
    appsService = TestBed.inject(AppsService);
    guard = TestBed.inject(AppEssentialsGuard);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it( 'should open new default app window', () => {
    spyOn(window, 'open');
    let returnValue = guard.canActivate(null, null);
    expect( window.open ).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://appstore.com/");
    expect(returnValue).toBeFalsy();
  });


});
```

Now for the happy flow test, I am using the AppsServiceMock specified in useClass, which returns an array of dummy apps, including one with the ID 'def' for the test to pass.

My question is, I also want to test the case that this url returns an empty array, or one without the 'def' app, how can I test both cases? I don't know how to use another mock

I am new to Jasmine

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the behavior you are looking for by spying on `getAllApps` and returning a value before making assertions. Spying on and returning a value ignores the original details implementation and will always return the value you specify.

```
// happy path;
it( 'should open new default app window', () => {
    spyOn(appService, 'getAllApps').and.returnValue([/* add an array of elements you would like */]);
    spyOn(window, 'open');
    let returnValue = guard.canActivate(null, null);
    expect( window.open ).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://appstore.com/");
    expect(returnValue).toBeFalsy();
  });
// empty array path
it( 'should not open new default app window', () => {
    spyOn(appService, 'getAllApps').and.returnValue([]);
    spyOn(window, 'open');
    let returnValue = guard.canActivate(null, null);
    expect( window.open ).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // change your assertion here
    expect(returnValue).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Comment: this doesnt work, spyOn doesnt override the original value @AliF50

Comment: Weird, I feel like what I have provided should work.

Comment: i realize i have delay() in the function being tested, could that affect how it works maybe? @AliF50

Comment: I don't see a delay in your question but if you have it in a different instance, yes it might. I would use `fakeAsync` and `tick` for a `delay`. Testing async and time can be difficult.